# what should be used to make Text widget clickable?

Tags: flutter-layout

What should we use as a parent to make Text widget click. Because text doesn't have any click function.

I have used InkWell for this. But i dont know the ideal widget for it.

Comment: Finding an _Ideal_ widget will depend on your exact use case. You can wrap your `Text` widget in a `GestureDetector`, but it won't give the ripple animation when tapped on. Using an `InkWell` widget gives the ripple animation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i hope it will help.